# Programmatically disable Android OS upgrades?

Tags: android, upgrade

We are the software development department of a company that makes industrial equipment and we have some Samsung Galaxy-Tab 4 tablets that we use as "remote controls" for the manufacturing equipment, using an app we wrote ourselves for the purpose and installed directly from Android Studio. This app is not distributed to other devices.  We bought these tablets online, right out of the box from Samsung, i.e., there is no phone company or common carrier involved. These tablets are not registered with Google, i.e., there is no gmail account associated with them; in fact we can't even access Google Play with them.  I unboxed these tablets myself and never registered them with with Google or Samsung.

So I was surprised when I came in this morning and saw a notice on the screen of one that a scheduled software update has been downloaded and was ready to go. It says it's 876.87 MB and it wants to do an OS upgrade to Lollipop.

I have no idea where the upgrade is coming from or how it's initiated. My concern is that if this happens at a customer site or trade show an unexpected upgrade could break our software or cause other mischief.   **Is there a way I can programmatically disable software upgrades?**

Comment: If your product is tied to both hardware and software you should probably just fork the Android OS and put it on the tablets before selling them. Apps are sandboxed and can only access their own stuff and are pretty dumb when it comes to things outside that sandbox (the OS).

In most cases an update shouldn't break your app, if it does then probably look at the software quality you are selling to customers.

Your other option is to just disable automatic updates on the tablets before sending them out to customers.

Comment: I don't know what any of that means.   ("Fork the OS"?)  We're not building our own OS from source code (and don't have the resources here to become OS developers).   This is the stock OS that came on these, not some custom black-market OS of unknown provenance.  Also, we don't sell this to customers - it's used at trade shows and by field engineers.

Comment: "I have no idea where the upgrade is coming from" -- Google, by way of Samsung, via your network connection. "how it's initiated" -- the device checks for updates periodically. "Is there a way I can programmatically disable software upgrades?" -- unless there is something in the device owner APIs that I'm not seeing, then no.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100991/how-do-i-skip-an-android-system-update-and-stop-its-notifications

Comment: If you want to disable the OS updates you would have to do it at the OS level which would mean forking AOSP and rolling your own version of Android. I gave this example to highlight how ludicrous your request is however if you want to ensure they can't update their device that would be how you'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

As an app developer, no you cannot control firmware upgrades. They come from either the carrier, or if it's a wi-fi tablet, the manufacturer.

Your only option is to control the firmware. That means building your own firmware dist of Android for your chosen hardware. You can then disable (or otherwise control) the firmware update schedule / process my making changes in the firmware.

Owning the firmware is a very big deal compared to deploying an app.

Answer (score 0):

> I was surprised when I came in this morning and saw a notice on the screen of one that a scheduled software update

as a software developer I cannot understand your surprise. It's a very well known (and often criticise feature due to slow/delayed roll out) feature of the OS

> I have no idea where the upgrade is coming from or how it's initiated

Those come from the device manufacturer (you said Samsung, right?) and do not need a login or account of any type. It's coded somewhere deep inside the OS to check the manufacturer server for updates. Same that happens with Windows, Mac OS, Linux or iOS.

There is absolutely nothing an app can do to disable the OS update from an API point of view. This would be a major security flaw. One can easily imagine a malicious app exploiting a known OS vulnerability and blocking the OS from update itself that would patch the vulnerability.

**possible solutions for your case**

Apart from creating your own custom OS to control the process the only possible way that I can think of, is to host your own VPN server that blocks the update server (or blocks the whole internet expect the resources you want to access from your app) and configure the device to this VPN under `Settings -> WiFi`.

ps.: I saw the mentioned [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100991/how-do-i-skip-an-android-system-update-and-stop-its-notifications) and I would advise against disabling system services (or at least test A LOT after you diable it) because that could cause other issues.